# Server Error or mine?

Tags: linux, web-hosting

I have a website ( http://www.direshouseofsport.com ) that was working properly until today. Suddenly, the website will not let me login and my browser throws the following error:

`The connection was reset. The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.`

In the error logs, I see: `[Thu Aug 16 00:10:05 2012] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) 'localhost' does NOT match server name` three times.

The website seems to have lost all its styles too. I am on a shared host, in my public files I cannot access `index.php` (the browser throws the same error as above), and my control panel is DirectAdmin.

I didn't touch anything in my website so I thought this could be a server error. Do you guys have any idea what is happening?

Comment: Looks fine to me, have you tried clearing your browser cache and reloading it? Also, is your browser requesting HTTP or HTTPS? The error you're getting in the logs is only a warning and shouldn't really affect anything if you're not using HTTPS.

Comment: for future, try: http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/

Comment: Thank you guys. @JamesYale I cleared the catch, but still I see the site without css and I couldn't also login in to the pages login feature anymore. Is there anyother way? I also used Crome, but still the same problem. All other sites work. I don't know if this is a right question here, but can you suggest me ways? Thanks again.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1):

As the site is working for others, including myself, the conclusion must be that the problem is at your end. The log entry referring to the certificate is common on shared hosts, where the system will never have the same name as your site and certificates are commonly shared amongst clients. This should produce a warning for any client that connects via HTTPS but can be ignored if your site is just HTTP.

Comment: so I guess you can see this website with the full style (?), in that case, I will have to clear the catches from my browser (?) or do you suggest anyother solution? thanks.

Comment: Do you have any other caches under your control, such as a proxy? Clearing the cache(s) should be the first step whenever a web site doesn't display correctly.

Comment: I don't use proxies and I cleared the catches both in the chrome and firefox, but weirdly enough I can't login at http://www.direshouseofsport.com/login, it throws 'The connection was reset' in Firefox and the website comes without the style, and when I see the links on Firebug, it shows that the links to the styles is redirected to some other folder, when I edited it on Firebug it works, but I couldn't edit the source file since this problem is only in my computer. Any ideas?

Comment: Without seeing the code I have no idea.

Comment: w/n I load the index (w/h ends up without styles),Firebug says `This element has no style rules.You can create a rule for it`.when I see the code with 'ViewSource' on the website,there are style links like this´<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/index.php/tools/css/themes/house_of_sport/css/960_24_col.css" />´ in w/h when I click that the browser displays 'the connection was reset'. And the link to this style is not on the right directory, it is found in different directory. Of course, when I change the link on Firebug it starts rendering the styles onto the browser.does this help?

Comment: We're getting way off topic here but the problem is the links. I'm pretty sure `href="/index.php/tools/css/themes/house_of_sport/css/960_24_col.css` is wrong because normally you would never include a php file in the URL like that. Don't ask me why the site appeared fine for me though.